# Is it possible to put a string array into buffered Reader?

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I'm working on a project at the moment which requires me to set up a distributed network simulator, I had it working with taking output from a file and parsing through each line with a buffered reader as you can see below but I want to now use a predefined array and make my bufferedReader take input from that instead I've looked up a few solutions online to help me put this array into the buffered Reader but non seem to have worked.

I'm getting no errors when running and terminating the code but just seems to be stuck in an endless loop at some point and I presume it's the new buffered reader segment using the array instead. The idea behind this was to make the process simpler than re-writing many segments to fit around the array parsing and instead find a simpler way by having the array in the buffered Reader but as this is proving difficult I may have to resort to changing. I have tested if the array is being initialised correctly and that's not the problem so it's one less thing to take into consideration.

```
**Previous code:**
 private void parseFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Parsing Array");
        Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            String line = null;
            line = br.readLine(); // Skip first line
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                parseLine(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException x) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
        }
    }
```

The recommendation online was to use an input stream with the buffered reader for it but that didn't seem to work at all as it over wrote the array, any recommendations on what I can use for the buffered reader segment would be grand.

The Array method above is just a void creating the array which is called before the method so the array should be initialised I presume, If anyone can look over and potentially let me know where I'm going wrong and problems that would be amazing if not I appreciate your time to read this anyway, Thanks for your time.

```
New Code Attempt:
//Creating array to parse.
private void createArray(){
    myStringArray[0] = "Node_id Neighbours";
    myStringArray[1] = "1 2 10";
    myStringArray[2] = "2 3 1";
    myStringArray[3] = "3 4 2";
    myStringArray[4] = "4 5 3";
    myStringArray[5] = "5 6 4";
    myStringArray[6] = "6 7 5";
    myStringArray[7] = "7 8 6";
    myStringArray[8] = "8 9 7";
    myStringArray[9] = "9 10 8";
    myStringArray[10] = "10 1 9";
    myStringArray[11] = "ELECT 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";
}

private void parseArray() throws IOException {
    //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    System.out.println("Parsing Array");

    // try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path))
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
        for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
        {
            String line = null;
            line = br.readLine(); // Skip first line
            while ((myStringArray[i] = br.readLine()) != null) {
                parseLine(line);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", x);
    }
}
```

Answer: You cannot do this with buffered reader. I fixed it like this if this is any use to anyone. Thanks a lot to @L.Spillner for the explanation and answer.

code fix:

```
    private void parseArray() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Parsing Array");

    for(int i=1;i<12;i++) //First row ignored.
        {
            String line = null;
            line = myStringArray[i];
            //Begin parsing process of each entity.
            parseLine(line);

        }
}
```

Comment: I am still a little confused, you are assigning the incoming String to a specific field in the array and then try to parse the line you attempted to skip. That is what i mean: `while((myStringArray[i] = br.readLine()) != null){parseLine(line);}`. What you have done, is, you have stored everything into the array and therefore overwritten any data within it with the input from the console (since isr is and InputStream Reader of stdin/System.in)

Comment: @L.Spillner I see what you mean, the InputStream was just a recommendation online for a way to get the array into the reader, I'll get rid of the input stream and look into it more, thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: Well for some kind of reason i think you did not have understood the `BufferedReader` by now. Correct me if i am wrong but you want to **put** the array **into** the `BufferedReader`? If so the answer is simple. You can not. Take a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) for more precise information. In short: The only purpose of the BufferedReader is, to read characters from an `Reader`. Reader themselfs are just an abstract structure to handle character `InputStreams`.

Comment: @L.Spillner Yes that was the main objective, I wanted to find a way for the bufferedReader to get the array but if I cannot that's fine! thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Let's kick it off with a precise answer to the Question.

**You cannot put anything into a `BufferedReader` directly.** Especially when it's some kind of data structure like an array.

The `BufferedReader`'s purpose is to handle I/O Operations, input operations to be more precise. According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html) the `BufferedReader` takes a `Reader` as an argument. `Reader` is an abstract class which contains 'tools' to handle character `InputStreams`.

The way the `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` method works is: Any character arriving on the `InputStream` gets stored in a buffer until a `\n` (new line/linefeed) or `\r` (carriage retun) arrives. When one of these two special characters show up the buffer gets interpreted as a String and is returned to the call.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is you can't. Thanks for the feedback though guys and got it working through just looping through the array and assigning each item to line.

Comment: If anyone would like the full simulators code please feel free to ask and I'll provide a link for the classes.